# PowerShell Group Hash Table by Value Which is an Array to Get Count

Tags: arrays, powershell, hashtable

Pulling information from SQL, I gather a device name, AppownerPrimary, Secondary, and Tertiary email address. There could be 0 to 3 email addresses. For this problem, we can essentially disregard the device name.

[image]

I throw this information into a hash table using a foreach loop:

```
$DeviceList = @{}

$DeviceLists  = (Invoke-Sqlcmd  -Serverinstance $ServerInstance -Database $Database -Query "select devicename, appownerprimaryemail, Secondary, Tertiary from dbo.Table order by AppOwnerPrimaryEmail")

foreach ($item in $devicelists)
{
if($item.appownerprimaryemail -and $item.Secondary -and $item.Tertiary)
{
    $DeviceList += @{$item.DeviceName = "$($item.AppOwnerPrimaryEmail)", "$($item.Secondary)", "$($item.Tertiary)"}
}
elseif ($item.appownerprimaryemail -and $item.Secondary -and !$item.Tertiary)
{
    $DeviceList += @{$item.DeviceName = "$($item.AppOwnerPrimaryEmail)", "$($item.Secondary)"}
}
elseif ($item.appownerprimaryemail -and !$item.Secondary -and !$item.Tertiary)
{
    $DeviceList  += @{$item.DeviceName = "$($item.AppOwnerPrimaryEmail)"}
}
}
```

The hash table ends up looking like this:

[image]

I simply need to get the count of each time a unique email grouping appears. When I started writing the script, there was only one email and I am sorting by email in the SQL query, so I was able to use group-object:

```
    [array]$UniqueEmails = $DeviceList.Values | Group-Object
```

Now that there could be 0-3, group object is not working, at all. It seems to be grouping all of the emails together for every device. I know that group-object does not like hashtables, but I'm not certain on why so f you know why this is happening, I would love an explanation. However, the point of this post is that I simply need a count of each unique value string.

Using this example, I would expect this output

[image]

You can replicate the issue by running this:

```
$Devicelist = @{"Device1" = "Sally.Johnson@Domain.com"; "Device7" = "Sally.Johnson@Domain.com"; "Device8" = "Sally.Johnson@Domain.com"; "Device2" = "Bob.Davis@domain.com", "Jane.Doe@domain.com"; "Device3" = "Bob.Davis@domain.com", "Jane.Doe@domain.com"; "Device4" = "Jane.Doe@domain.com", "Sally.Johnson@domain.com", "Bob.Davis@domain.com"; "Device5" = "Jane.Doe@domain.com", "Sally.Johnson@domain.com", "Bob.Davis@domain.com"; "Device6" = "Jane.Doe@domain.com", "Sally.Johnson@domain.com", "Bob.Davis@domain.com"}
[array]$UniqueEmails = $DeviceList.values | Group-Object
```

I think that I need to enumerate and loop through every item in the array of the values of the hash table, but at the same time I need to treat them as a group so I'm at a loss. Any help is greatly appreciated.

If I'm not clear, please let me know and I will do my best to explain better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$devicelist = @{
    "Device1" = "Sally.Johnson@Domain.com";
    "Device7" = "Sally.Johnson@Domain.com";
    "Device8" = "Sally.Johnson@Domain.com";
    "Device2" = "Bob.Davis@domain.com", "Jane.Doe@domain.com";
    "Device3" = "Bob.Davis@domain.com", "Jane.Doe@domain.com";
    "Device4" = "Jane.Doe@domain.com", "Sally.Johnson@domain.com", "Bob.Davis@domain.com";
    "Device5" = "Jane.Doe@domain.com", "Sally.Johnson@domain.com", "Bob.Davis@domain.com";
    "Device6" = "Jane.Doe@domain.com", "Sally.Johnson@domain.com", "Bob.Davis@domain.com"
}

$uniqueEmails = @{}

# Get all the values in the list, sort them
# and for each, use the value as the key in the unique emails list
# then for that key add 1 every time the key repeats
$devicelist.Values | Sort | % { $uniqueEmails["$_"] += 1 }

Write-Host ($uniqueEmails | Out-String)

# Outputs
Name                           Value
----                           ---- -
Sally.Johnson@Domain.com       3
Jane.Doe@domain.com Sally.J... 3
Bob.Davis@domain.com Jane.D... 2
```

**Update**

I tested this on Posh v1, Posh v2 and Posh v3, and it works fine on 2012 Server R2 as well. The issues must be with your server. Run $PSVersionTable.PSVersion and see what version you are using.

You can start any older Posh version with: powershell -version 1|2|3.

Comment: What what is the `+= 1` supposed to do? It throws the error `Cannot convert value "Sally.Johnson@Domain.com" to type "System.Int32". Error: "Input string was not in a correct format."`

Comment: It's increments the count for that value. The code works as I have it pasted, your issue is that whatever your device list data is, it doesn't match the $deviceList I have.

Comment: Copying and pasting directly from your reply yields the same error messages, using the device list that you had posted. I'm on PS Version 5.0.10586.117

Comment: I'm on version 5.1, I updated this to check for the key, did you try it?

Comment: Yes and copying and pasting everything from your reply throws the same "System.Int32" error. Changing it to `$uniqueEmails += @{$_ = 1 }` worked, now I'm just trying to figure out how to increment it.

Comment: I don't know how to help you anymore. The code works fine on Windows 10 under Posh 5.1. Was it you that downvoted my answer?

Comment: You're right, I found a Win10 PC to test on and it does work. It doesn't work on Server 2012 R2. How odd, I'll have to figure that out. Thank you!

Comment: Now that I know that, let me look into it, I'll come up with a working answer for Server 2012.

Comment: PS Version 5.0.10586.117